# При запуске vim включение NERDTree

Tags: vim, vimrc

В заголовке все сказано. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш файл vimrc такую строчку, как описано в [FAQ на GitHub](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree#faq).

```
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
```